# How to put 2 condition after AS in a procedure

Tags: oracle

I want to put 2 condition after the keyword AS in a procedure which are INVALID_BUDGET EXCEPTION and Event_ID varchar2(8) but this will cause error in oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_ADD_OVER_BUDGET_EVENT(V_EventType IN VARCHAR,V_EventBudget IN NUMBER,V_organizerID IN VARCHAR,v_FoodBeverage IN NUMBER,v_wine IN NUMBER ,v_Decoration IN NUMBER,v_rentalfee IN NUMBER,v_facility IN NUMBER) 

AS INVALID_BUDGET EXCEPTION AND Event_ID varchar2(8);

PRAGMA exception_init(INVALID_BUDGET,-20000);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Event values ( next_eventid_seq,v_eventType,v_eventbudget,null,null,null,v_organizerID) RETURNING EVENTid INTO event_ID;


    INSERT INTO EventCost values (next_Costid_seq,v_FoodBeverage,v_Wine,v_Decoration,v_RentalFee,v_Facility,event_ID);
    EXCEPTION WHEN INVALID_BUDGET THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(u'\000A' || 'Please enter budget of above 50000.');
End;
/
```

How to put the two condition in a procedure without any error.

Extra question: Can procedure handle two exception handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable definitions are separated by a semi-colon:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_ADD_OVER_BUDGET_EVENT
  (V_EventType IN VARCHAR,
   V_EventBudget IN NUMBER,
   V_organizerID IN VARCHAR,
   v_FoodBeverage IN NUMBER,
   v_wine IN NUMBER,
   v_Decoration IN NUMBER,
   v_rentalfee IN NUMBER,
   v_facility IN NUMBER) 
AS
  INVALID_BUDGET  EXCEPTION;
  Event_ID        varchar2(8);

  PRAGMA exception_init(INVALID_BUDGET,-20000);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Event
    values (next_eventid_seq, v_eventType, v_eventbudget,
            null, null, null, v_organizerID)
    RETURNING EVENTid INTO event_ID;

  INSERT INTO EventCost
    values (next_Costid_seq, v_FoodBeverage, v_Wine, v_Decoration,
            v_RentalFee, v_Facility, event_ID);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN INVALID_BUDGET THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(u'\000A' || 'Please enter budget of above 50000.');
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(u'\000A' || 'Attempt to insert duplicate value ' ||
                         SQLERRM);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(u'\000A' || 'Something bad happened! ' || SQLERRM);
End;
```

And you can add as many exception handlers to your exception block as you want.

Best of luck.

Comment: This is not work for me.     These error appear in the second insert statement  12/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
12/17    PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Comment: That means that your INSERT statement isn't supplying all the values needed for your table. It's a good idea to always include a field list with your INSERT statements, and to match up the values to the field names - that way you can more easily figure out what's wrong. But as I don't have access to your tables or your database there's not much I can do to help you at this point. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple exception handling in oracle you can use this syntax. The exception-handling block contains series of WHEN condition to handle the exception.

```
BEGIN
<execution block>
.
.
EXCEPTION
WHEN <exceptionl_name>
THEN
  <Exception handling code for the “exception 1 _name’' >
WHEN OTHERS
THEN
  <Default exception handling code for all exceptions >
END;
```

[Please refer the link](https://www.guru99.com/exception-handling-pl-sql.html)